# How do you "Save as" /"open" a document using a Python Tkinter interface

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

Lets say I have a document file named `sample.docx` added to an IDE python project. I have a python tkinter program and I want the user to be a able to click a button that will automatically open the `sample.docx` file. I think the only way is by opening the windows save as window with the file already loaded.

How do I do this?

Comment: I'm not clear on why you believe that you're supposed to open a file by saving it (specifically from its default application's "Save As..." dialog, for some reason), but it doesn't work that way.

Comment: As in they press a button and the "save as" dialog pops up with the file samle.docx already loaded.

Comment: Then you need [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7094324/how-to-use-python-saveas-dialog) and some [documentation](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-file-dialogs.htm). Please do additional independent research.

Comment: with open('sample.docx') as f: process(f)