# How to make a save function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I made a notepad clone in python but I am stuck. 
I want to change the doNothing() Function to be a Save function.
I want the user to be able to name the file he wrote in the program and save it where he wants.

```
from tkinter import *

# ********** Functions **********
def doNothing():
print("Ok, i won't!")

# ********** TK Initialization **********
root = Tk()
# ********** Main Menu **********
menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)

subMenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=subMenu)
subMenu.add_command(label="New", command=doNothing)
subMenu.add_command(label="Open...", command=doNothing)
subMenu.add_command(label="Save", command=doNothing)
subMenu.add_command(label="Save As...", command=doNothing)
subMenu.add_separator()
subMenu.add_command(label="Page Setup...", command=doNothing)
subMenu.add_command(label="Print...", command=doNothing)
subMenu.add_separator()
subMenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.quit)

editMenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=editMenu)
editMenu.add_command(label="Undo", command=doNothing)
editMenu.add_separator()
editMenu.add_command(label="Cut", command=doNothing)
editMenu.add_command(label="Copy", command=doNothing)
editMenu.add_command(label="Paste", command=doNothing)
editMenu.add_command(label="Delete", command=doNothing)
editMenu.add_separator()
editMenu.add_command(label="Find...", command=doNothing)
editMenu.add_command(label="Find Next", command=doNothing)
editMenu.add_command(label="Replace...", command=doNothing)
editMenu.add_command(label="Go To...", command=doNothing)
editMenu.add_separator()
editMenu.add_command(label="Select All", command=doNothing)
editMenu.add_command(label="Time/Date", command=doNothing)

FormatMenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="Format", menu=FormatMenu)
FormatMenu.add_command(label="Word Wrap", command=doNothing)
FormatMenu.add_command(label="Font...", command=doNothing)

ViewMenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="View", menu=ViewMenu)
ViewMenu.add_command(label="Status Bar", command=doNothing)

HelpMenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=HelpMenu)
HelpMenu.add_command(label="View Help", command=doNothing)
HelpMenu.add_separator()
HelpMenu.add_command(label="About Editor", command=doNothing)

AboutMenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="About", menu=AboutMenu)
AboutMenu.add_command(label="About the Developer", command=doNothing)
AboutMenu.add_separator()
AboutMenu.add_command(label="FK YOALL", command=doNothing)



# ********** Status Bar **********
status = Label(root, text="Preparing to do nothing...", bd=1, relief=SUNKEN, 
anchor=W)
status.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)

# ********** Text Area **********
text = Text(root, height=100, width=200)
text.pack()

# ********** Window Properties **********
root.maxsize(width=800, height=680)
root.minsize(width=666, height=666)
root.title('Text Editor')
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

There are three steps that you have to implement:

1. Retrieve the text inside your `Text` widget. You can do this with the [`Text.get`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14824164/7306999) method.
2. Prompt the user for a path where the text file is to be saved. You can do this with `tkinter` function [`filedialog.asksaveasfilename`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7094628/7306999).
3. Write a text file with the text from step 1 and the path from step 2. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9536741/7306999) for a simple example.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `os.system(command)` importing the library `os` to create, rename or move files like batch. In `command` you need to put the batch command. To learn batch, see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DOS_commands)